# OnClickerListener issue, can open the app in emulator

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to the Android studio and trying to make first steps. I just wanted to do some action while clicking button. When I ran the emulator it told me that app stopped running and every time I clicked it's icon it did the same. Then I removed OnClickerListener Function and then app started perfectly. Even if the body of this Function is empty it does not run. So what should I do?

```
package com.example.firstapp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        bigButt.setOnClickListener {

        }
    }
}
```

So this code can't run the app. Even if the body is empty. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you instantiate bigButt?

Comment: If you mean if I have put it on the App board, I've done it and also sticked it as follows. If you mean something else, can u explain?

Comment: To be able to do bigButt.setOnClickListener, bigButt should be declared somewhere in onCreate as a variable or at the class level as a property.

Comment: I think it's declared, Im working in android studio and when Im putting button or something(object) else on the activity I think its automatically is declared. Or maybe Im mistaken?